# .NET Core Web Api Error -4090 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available on Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 1.1 Web Api project that works great locally. Once I deploy it to AppService on Azure, it will not respond to any GET requests - they all time out. I have an open ping endpoint that simply returns current date and time and it is not responding. Looking at the logs I see this:

```
[INF] Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using '"D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys"' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest. (383ad3af)
[WRN] Unable to bind to http://localhost:22676 on the IPv6 loopback interface. (de7f78a0)
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -4090 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4090 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4090 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Object state)<---
```

I am not sure why this is happening and how to resolve it.

EDIT: Here is the Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
            .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddDebug())
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ThreadCount = 1;
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

Comment: show how you configure host (by default - 'Main' method in Program.cs file). Have you added '.UseAzureAppServices()' there?

Comment: Added Program.cs. I did not use UseAzureAppServices(). Is that required?

Comment: I added the dependency and included a call to UseAzureAppServices() but it made no difference.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue with ASP.NET Core 2.0. Specify the urls explicitly that the host will listen on:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://+:22676") // <--add urls
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
}
```

Comment: Solution works but please explain what is happening when we specify urls explicitly

Comment: @ManishJain by default asp.net core binds to localhost:5000. ```UseUrls``` can change this binding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0#endpoint-configuration

Answer (score 1):

This turned to be an issue with my firewall. Message in the log is just a warning and doesn't seem to interfere with normal processing.